# Msp430 Launchpad Soldering

Tags: msp430

I m newbie.I don't want to ruin my board.I searched and found crysal soldering to launchpad.But there is msp430 launchpad pins too.Can I solder pins directly or should I use male header or female header.I said that pins like 1.6 1.7..... Can i solder them directly

Comment: It's hard to understand the question you are trying to ask.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's quite obvious to anyone with a Launchpad!

Answer (score 11):

The crystal should be close to the chip - use the pads provided.

For most applications a crystal isn't necessary as it's got a very stable on-chip oscillator.

Comment: +1 Long traces can easily ruin the oscillator, especially with a > 8MHz crystal.

Answer (score 1):

The crystal location is placed there because it's a critical thing for a clock reference, as Leon said. Place the crystal at that location.

An alternative is, what I've seen very similar on some of the olimex microcontroller boards, is to use **female** pin headers at the location. You can slide a crystal in there and swap it with another one whenever necessary. However, this might not be the best and reliable connection, as it might not be a perfect fit (and make very poor contact).

Personally, if you want to use the board occasionally, take 1 crystal you think you'll use most often and place it right in there. I also believe the boards very sold for a very very low price, so you may as well get another one and place another crystal on there, if you're a bit anxious with desoldering and soldering.

Comment: It's a surface-mount crystal, headers can't be used.

Comment: I really do see holes at the crystal symbol on this picture of the MSP430 launchpad: https://jp.rs-online.com/largeimages/R7122649-01.jpg
  However, I also see that XIN and XOUT are routed outwards to, possibly, a pinheader.. Odd.

Comment: You are right, I just checked one of my boards. They are brought out to pins as the same connections can be used for I/O, if the crystal isn't used.